# php proxy doesn't understand url params

Tags: php, proxy, url-parameters

Because of CORS restrictions I need to reach a url via proxy. I've implemented a very simple script in php:

```
<?php 
$url=$_GET['purl'];//globals are already decoded
header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
readfile("http://".$url);
?>
```

the url I want to read is something like this:

someserver.com/blah/ads?env=vp&gdfp_req=1&impl=s&output=xml_vast2&unviewed_position_start=1&url=www.somewebsite.com

so I try:

localhost/proxy.php?purl=someserver.com/blah/ads?env=vp&gdfp_req=1&impl=s&output=xml_vast2&unviewed_position_start=1&url=www.somewebsite.com

if I execute this, I get the following error:

This page contains the following errors:
error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

I've checked the file and there's no such extra content, and the document is well formed

However, debbuging the script I found that only the first parameter is printed:

```
<?php 
$url=$_GET['purl'];//globals are already decoded
echo $url;
die();
header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
readfile("http://".$url);
?>
```

it prints:

someserver.com/blah/ads?env=vp

Notice I have 2 interrogation marks on the url: one for my script and the second one for the third party script.

I've been into this issue for hours. How can I reach this kind of url via proxy?

Answer (score 0):

```
localhost/proxy.php?purl=someserver.com/blah/ads?env=vp&gdfp_req=1&impl=s&output=xml_vast2&unviewed_position_start=1&url=www.somewebsite.com

$_GET["purl"]
$_GET["env"]
$_GET["gdfp_req"]
$_GET["output"]
```

and so on you can print all your URL

So in that case use:
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
and than parse the url

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem with this aproach is that parameters are dynamically generated, besides the fact that this proxy serves several url, not just this particular case (in all other cases it works fine)

Comment: Edited, Hope it can help!

Comment: Ok, I've been doing some refactor, and now it works. The modified proxy looks like this:

<?php 
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = str_replace('/myowndomain/proxy.php?purl=', '', $url);
$url = str_replace('%3F', '?', $url);//? mark is encoded
header("Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8");
readfile("http://".$url);
?>
However, I still don't get it what's happening with $_GET. Any clues?